# Powershell script not progressing while "choose file to upload" window is up

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, sendkeys

I have a script that navigates to a website, logs in, then clicks a button to upload a file to that website.

After clicking the button a prompt comes up and I've so far figured out that SendKeys is a possible solution. However, the script gets stuck once the window shows up.

Here's my kode:

```
$upload = $ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "userfile"}
$upload.click()
$wshell.SendKeys("c:\path_to_my_file")
```

I even tried testing it with a Write-host. In this case it only prints to the console AFTER I manually press the "cancel" button on the "Choose file to upload"

```
$upload = $ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "userfile"}
$upload.click()

Write-Host "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use AutoHotkey for that. Instead of `$wshell.SendKeys` you will use AHKs `Send` function. You can run this script from within powershell script or before it (it could wait for the choosefile dialog to appear and automatically insert the file name when it does). This would go something like:

```
start WaitForPrompt.ahk
$upload = $ie.Document.body.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.Name -match "userfile"}
$upload.click()
```

WaitForPrompt.ahk

```
WinActivate <title of the window that appears>
Send c:\path_to_my_file
```

Other then that, you could avoid all of this (it will certainly work tho) by using `Invoke-WebRequest` and crafting form POST. For that you need to see what kind of stuff browser sends to the server and you have various plugins for this (i.e. firefox's temperdata). In Chrome you could see this and get the `curl` command from developers tools that could be executed from the shell as is.

Comment: Would love to find out how to do this without third party software, so that sort of rules out AHK. Invoke-WebRequest looks interesting though. Is there some way to visibly follow the progress of it, such as in the console? (eg. Knowing whether it logs in successfully and uses the correct button and stuff)

Comment: AHK is a go-to tool for this type of thing (its portable ~300kb exe that you can put next to the script, get it from chocolatey or whatever..). IMO, it should be there in Windows from the start as a native tool.

Comment: `iwr` wont click any buttons. You need to craft POST request and pass it form data via `body` argument. See `man iwr -examples`. This is way more bulletproof then any key sending and similar.

Comment: iwr would also work without GUI (i.e. on nano/core server).

Comment: Been messing around alittle with the iwr. How do I handle being redirected? I'm not able to get the forms needed on the site I'm redirected to, since it's still using the forms for the previous site.

Sorry if I'm being annoying

Comment: If you are redirected response header will contain `Location` of redirection. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/majkinetor/chocolatey/blob/master/nexus-oss/update.ps1) example that handles redirection (it doesn't user iwr but its similar). You will get this too with iwr and do another request.